# Import Text data to Greenplum database

Tags: sql, database, bash, greenplum

I have a text file with some data and wants to import data to Greenplum database.After online research , I found that its better to use COPY command if your data size is small. So i decided to use this.
Here is the scenario:
I have placed my Text file at location   **/bin/bash /data** , I can access this file using terminal, but once I run the following COPY sql script at Greenplum database it's says :
**could not open file "/bin/bash /data/data.txt" for reading: No such file or directory**
Below is the my sql script:

```
COPY userdata(customerid,time,trans,quantity) from '/bin/bash /data/data.txt' WITH DELIMITER ',';
```

From Greenplum database documentation I found the following line :
**The COPY source file must be accessible to the master host. Specify the COPY source file name relative to the master host location.**
But I do not know how to make it accessible to master host and relative to master host location.

Comment: location `/bin/bash /data` doesn't make any sense. Please consider including the right path to your datafile.

Comment: I was accessing location by /bin/bash /data, because i am running Greenplum database on image of Cent OS through Docker container.  Files of Container ( here Cent OS ) get stored at this path  /bin/bash /data.

Comment: That path sounds weird to me.. Would you mind telling how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Initially it was also wired for me and i asked my teacher and she said it works like that :)  and for solution part of this problem , I did the exactly  as you said and it worked. I removed the  /bin/bash part.

Comment: Switch teacher by all means then ;)

Comment: Ha ha :)
planning to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your file doesn't make any sense.

`/bin/bash /data/data.txt` is certainly not a valid name for a path.

If you `data.txt` file is located in the `/data` folder with content
in the following format :

```
12345,5:32AM,air,2
67890,6:42PM,rail,4
```

You could use the below command :

```
COPY userdata(customerid,time,trans,quantity) FROM '/data/data.txt' WITH DELIMITER AS ',';
```

Also **sql user** you should have the permission to access the the `data.txt` from the location `/data` folder.

Perhaps do a `ls -l` and check if the **sql user** can read files from `data.txt`